# Edit text showing not suitable for children gifs (GBoard)

Tags: android, android-edittext, gboard

I have this app that is made for kids and today I received a complaint that Gboard gifs is showing not suitable for kids gifs.

¿Do you know if there is any option I can disable the Gboard feature on my Edit Texts?

Maybe with android:inputType I can set an specific input type that do not show this, or an specific Edit Text type that do not integrates this Google Option?

It's funny because even using Youtube Kids I can see gifs that are totally 
inappropriate for users:

[image: Youtube Kids]

[image: Some zombies in Youtube Kids]

I guess Google didn't think about this when the mobile is used by a kid...

Comment: Interesting question - sounds to me as though these users would be better off installing another keyboard.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot force all my users to install other keyboard.

Comment: I'm just saying that the issue isn't with your app - it's with the keyboard. It doesn't matter whether a user is using your app, or Chrome or anything else - they will still be able to access inappropriate gifs. The only solution for them that will work in all cases is to install another keyboard.